# Searching through rows in adjacent column

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on a "warning system" of sorts that will trigger a message box when the constraints are met. For example, if the name "Bob" is found five times in column A, it will check column B to see if any of the other constraints are met, such as more than 5 occurrences of "Call Out". Lastly, if those constraints are met, it will look into column I to see if at least 2 of those occurrences were not an exception ("No"). However, I'm having a hard time deciding how to set it up. I thought about using a series of If statements like so:

```
Sub WarningSystem()
Dim SMNameCounter As Integer
Dim CategoryCounter As Integer
Dim ExceptionCounter As Integer
SMNameCounter = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A200"), "Bob")
If SMNameCounter = "2" Then
CategoryCounter = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B1:B200"), "Call Out")
    If CategoryCounter = "2" Then
        ExceptionCounter = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("I1:I200"), "No")
            If ExceptionCounter = "2" Then
                MsgBox "Warning! Bob has missed more than (" & CategoryCounter & ") days in a row. One more occurence will result in consequence"
            Else ' Do Nothing / No Trigger
            End If
    Else ' Do Nothing / No Trigger
    End If
Else ' Do Nothing / No Trigger
End If
End Sub
```

This is looking to be extremely tedious and hard to recreate for many variables. Could anyone point me in the right direction as to how I should be setting this up??

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that if Bob is in col A you want to check col B and col I of the same row, or any row? You might want to consider a pivot table.

Comment: Yes, checking them in the same row. I should've mentioned that this was a blatant error in my initial code as well - It's just looking through every cell of the column, not the corresponding row like I'd like it to. However, I'm not quite sure how to dictate that range with the way I'm trying to write it

Comment: Why are you doing this in VBA?  Looks like you could do a Nested `IF` function call to get the same information and make localized explicit row reference.

Comment: Honestly I'm much more comfortable with Word VBA, and I'm fairly new to excel VBA, as similar as they may be the differences are taking me a bit to get used to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to use `CountIfs` for the inner counts:

```
Sub WarningSystem()
    Dim SMNameCounter As Integer
    Dim CategoryCounter As Integer
    Dim ExceptionCounter As Integer
    SMNameCounter = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A200"), "Bob")
    If SMNameCounter = 5 Then
        CategoryCounter = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("A1:A200"), "Bob", _
                                                                 Range("B1:B200"), "Call Out")
        If CategoryCounter > 5 Then
            ExceptionCounter = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("A1:A200"), "Bob", _
                                                                      Range("B1:B200"), "Call Out", _
                                                                      Range("I1:I200"), "No")
            If ExceptionCounter >= 2 Then
                MsgBox "Warning! Bob has missed more than (" & CategoryCounter & ") days in a row. One more occurence will result in consequence"
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Edited to generate the error message for any name found in A1:A200

```
Sub WarningSystem()
    Dim SMNameCounter As Integer
    Dim CategoryCounter As Integer
    Dim ExceptionCounter As Integer
    Dim r As Long
    For r = 1 To 200
        'Count how many times the current value in column A has occurred up
        'to and including this row
        SMNameCounter = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A" & r), Cells(r, "A").Value)
        If SMNameCounter = 1 Then
            'Only do the rest of the processing if this was the first occurrence
            SMNameCounter = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A200"), Cells(r, "A").Value)
            If SMNameCounter = 5 Then
                CategoryCounter = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("A1:A200"), Cells(r, "A").Value, _
                                                                         Range("B1:B200"), "Call Out")
                If CategoryCounter > 5 Then
                    ExceptionCounter = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("A1:A200"), Cells(r, "A").Value, _
                                                                              Range("B1:B200"), "Call Out", _
                                                                              Range("I1:I200"), "No")
                    If ExceptionCounter >= 2 Then
                        MsgBox "Warning! " & Cells(r, "A").Value & " has missed more than (" & CategoryCounter & ") days in a row. One more occurrence will result in consequence"
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution - I needed some sort of counting function. Lastly, how could I get it to look for ANY name, not necessarily "Bob"? I need to set some kind of general variable. So if it sees any name more than 5 times, it checks to see if there are 5 call outs, etc.?

Comment: Thanks again YowE3k. With the addition of some ElseIfs I was able to cover (most) of the scenarios needed. Appreciate the help